# Determine protocol for website

Tags: c#, iis-6, c#-2.0, iis-5

I'm using IIS 6.
I need to determine whether a certain site is running under http or https.

I tried extracting all of the properties using 'DirectoryEntry' from: IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1 (1 is the site id in this example)

The following are the results.
If anyone knows of any other way of determining IIS6 protocol type programmatically, using 'DirectoryEntry' - please let me know

```
 AccessFlags = 513 
 AppIsolated = 2
 KeyType = IIsWebVirtualDir
 Path = c:\inetpub\wwwroot
 AppRoot = /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT 
 AppFriendlyName = Default Application 
 DefaultDoc = Default.htm,Default.asp,index.htm,iisstart.asp
 AnonymousPasswordSync = True
 DirBrowseFlags = 1073741886 
 CacheISAPI = True 
 CGITimeout = 300 
 AuthFlags = 1 
 ContentIndexed = True
 AspLogErrorRequests = True
 AspScriptFileCacheSize = 250
 AspScriptEngineCacheMax = 125
 AspExceptionCatchEnable = True
 AspTrackThreadingModel = False
 AspAllowOutOfProcComponents = True
 AspEnableAspHtmlFallback = False
 AspEnableChunkedEncoding = True
 AspEnableTypelibCache = True
 AspErrorsToNTLog = False
 AspProcessorThreadMax = 25
 AspRequestQueueMax = 3000
 AspMaxDiskTemplateCacheFiles = 1000
 AspAllowSessionState = True
 AspBufferingOn = True
 AspEnableParentPaths = True
 AspSessionTimeout = 20
 AspQueueTimeout = -1 
 AspCodepage = 0 
 AspScriptTimeout = 90 
 AspScriptErrorSentToBrowser = True 
 AppAllowDebugging = False
 AppAllowClientDebug = False
 AspKeepSessionIDSecure = False
 AspEnableApplicationRestart = True
 AspQueueConnectionTestTime = 3
 AspSessionMax = -1 AspLCID = 2048
 AnonymousUserName = IUSR_MASTER
 AspScriptLanguage = VBScript
 AspScriptErrorMessage = An error occurred on the server when processing the URL.  Please  contact the system administrator. 
 AnonymousUserPass = wl60A8PT[Cp@hE
 AspDiskTemplateCacheDirectory = %windir%\system32\inetsrv\ASP Compiled Templates  
 HttpCustomHeaders = X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
 KeyType = IIsCertMapper
```

Can any of these tell me if the protocol is Http or Https?
If not... does anyone know how to check it using C# on IIS 6?

Comment: What do you mean by 'running?' I site could have both http and https bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure : IIS [AccessSSLFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524954.aspx) property contains these informations.

If AccessSSL (hex 0x00000008) flag is set, it mean that SSL -ie https- is required, if not http is available.

As usual, you have to check this property on your IIS WebServer root directory since IIS logic is based on virtual dirs.

Path -> IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root

Comment: It seems to me that AccessSSLFlags only determines whether an SSL connection is _required_ to access the object, not whether there is an SSL binding for the site.

Comment: Yup, from the question : "I need to determine whether a certain site is running under http or https". If AccessSSL (hex 0x00000008) flag is set, it mean that SSL -ie https- is required, if not http is available (edited to add this). If the question is "how I can determine if I can connect to a certain site using https" the question must be more specific : https with server certificate or client certificate : the IIS configuration may differs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to look use the [SecureBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524481%28VS.90%29.aspx) property of a IIsWebServer object.

I tested the following code snippet on my own Windows Server 2003 with both SSL and non-SSL sites.

```
DirectoryEntry di = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://prodweb1/W3SVC/1");
PropertyValueCollection sslCertHashProperty = di.Properties["SSLCertHash"];
if (sslCertHashProperty.Count > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Site has associated SSL Certificate.");
}
PropertyValueCollection secureBindingsProperty = di.Properties["SecureBindings"];
if (secureBindingsProperty.Count > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Site has at least one SSL (https) binding.");
}
PropertyValueCollection serverBindingsProperty = di.Properties["ServerBindings"];
if (serverBindingsProperty.Count > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Site has at least one non-SSL (http) binding.");
}
```

Comment: Bindings only say on which Host:Port the site will accept SSL connections, it does not ensure that SSL communication is available/required for this website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metabase to tell.  I don't know why it isn't in you output, but there should be a property lik IsSecure=true to indicate that ssl is required.  I don't think that this property is set if ssl is optional.

Answer (score -1):

If you can wait until you receive a request, you can use [`Request.IsSecureConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection.aspx).

Comment: That's a pretty ugly solution... I'm looking for something smoother

Answer (score -1):

not that versed in C# but I believe you can load the web.config information in your application. There you should be abler to see if there is a specific security key indicating that SSL is configured on the server.

```
Configuration.AppSettings(<key>)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check the request object.
If SSL is being used:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"].ToLower() == "on"
```